# Flume Kafka integration error "producer.SyncProducer: Disconnecting from localhost:2181"

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

I am getting the following error:

```
s20/02/15 07:31:33 INFO producer.SyncProducer: Connected to localhost:2181 for producing
20/02/15 07:31:33 INFO producer.SyncProducer: Disconnecting from localhost:2181
20/02/15 07:31:33 WARN client.ClientUtils$: Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(flkf)] from broker [id:0,host:localhost,port:2181] failed
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
```

Comment: Please provide your Kafka and Flume configs

Comment: I have uploaded the files here: https://github.com/AbhishekDeepankar/File-Hosting

Comment: Don't link to github. Edit your question to include the full example of your setup and what command you run to get the result

Comment: I am trying to edit but it's showing that I have too much code in my question.

Comment: Your flume config isn't that long

Comment: I know, but that's what I am getting, i even tried "```", but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pointed flume at Zookeeper, not a **broker**. Try port 9092

Comment: I have tried 9092 already, It is saying connection could not be made.

Comment: Are you able to use Kafka console consumer and producer? Is Kafka running? What debugging have you done? Also-ran, don't use `tail -F` in flume. Use the spooldir source. Or use Kafka Connect, not Flume https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Comment: I am able to run producer and consumer manually, also tail -F is part of the project I am working on, can't help it.also tail -f is working while sending the data to spark directly and to HDFS.

Comment: Actually this time after restarting the KAFKA service and using port 9092, it actually worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read the flume documentation about not using tail and the spooldir source to read files